# Soap request authenticate php

Tags: php, soap

Hi Guys I am trying to make a request and get a response for authenticating my SOAP request.

I tried many different options but this one was the only one which gave me response(even an error 404).

This is my code

```
$client = new SOAPClient('http://devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService.svc?singleWsdl',
 array(
    'location' => 'http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService/IDirectoryService/Authenticate',
    'trace' => 1,
    'style' => SOAP_RPC,
    'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
  )
 );

$request = array(
  "BranchCode" => "xxx",
  "UserName" => "xxx",
  "Password" => "xxx",
  "Application" => "xxx",
  "Client" => "x",
  "BranchID" => 0
);

$result = array();

try {
    $result = $client->__soapCall('Authenticate', $request);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "SOAP Fault: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";
}

 echo "<pre>";
 echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequestHeaders())."\n";
 echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest())."\n";
 echo "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponseHeaders())."\n";
 echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
 echo "</pre>"; 

 var_dump($result);
```

What am i doing wrong? I dont get any response I get thsi

```
POST /DirectoryService/IDirectoryService/Authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.5.38
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction:"http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService/IDirectoryService/Authenticate"
Content-Length: 367


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Authenticate/><param1>xxx</param1><param2>xxx</param2><param3>xxx</param3><param4>x</param4><param5>0</param5></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found // Here
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 19 Mar 2018 13:34:51 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1245
```

This is the exact request I need to send :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dir="http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService">
    <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
         <dir:Authenticate>
           <dir:authenticateRequest BranchCode="xxx" UserName="xxx" Password="xxx" Application="xxx" Client="xxx">
           <dir:BranchID>xxx</dir:BranchID>
          </dir:authenticateRequest>
        </dir:Authenticate>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

EDIT: This is what I get on  raw from SoapUI:

```
POST http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/AirService HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService/IDirectoryService/Authenticate"
Content-Length: 602
Host: stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Please guys any help would be great, any feedback! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService/IDirectoryService/Authenticate` link does not exist. Your SOAP code is fine; it runs, the problem is with the URL you're passing in `'location'`

Comment: **Note**: removing that URL triggers a `500 Internal Server` error

Comment: Yes @Samuel i saw that. Is that something I have to change or is on the 3rd party error?

Comment: @Samuel from SoapUI I get this raw on success request

Comment: I would begin by checking the URL for any misspelled words... But also check the documentation for the specific API... your code is "fine", again it could be that the URL is malformed, but no logical or technical problems

Comment: reason is that if you actually go to that URL it will also just provide a 404 error, which is then pretty obvious there's nothing there.

Comment: Yes I know I change it , i removed( /Authenticate) 'http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService/IDirectoryService' and now I am getting this error "<Error><Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService/IDirectoryService'.</Message></Error>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the 'location' param from options, and call the Authenticate() function like this:

```
try {
    $result = $client->Authenticate(array('authenticateRequest'=>$request));
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
```

result:

```
POST /DirectoryService.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.6.32
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService/IDirectoryService/Authenticate"
Content-Length: 446


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Authenticate><ns1:authenticateRequest BranchCode="xxx" UserName="xxx" Password="xxx" Application="xxx" Client="x"><ns1:BranchID>0</ns1:BranchID></ns1:authenticateRequest></ns1:Authenticate></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 19 Mar 2018 14:06:43 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 522

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService"><AuthenticateResult Success="false" Narrative="Invalid details. Please check request. " CanBeOpenedInEditMode="false" ErrorCode="200002"><Token xsi:nil="true"/><Expiry xsi:nil="true"/></AuthenticateResult></AuthenticateResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["AuthenticateResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
    ["Success"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["Narrative"]=>
    string(39) "Invalid details. Please check request. "
    ["CanBeOpenedInEditMode"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["ErrorCode"]=>
    int(200002)
    ["Token"]=>
    NULL
    ["Expiry"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mlcansten that you so much... Exactly what I wanted.. I working.. Can you please let me know what's the difference calling it like that and worked? Thank you :D

Comment: The parameter passed to `Authenticate()` is `array('authenticateRequest'=>$request)` and not just `$request`

Comment: Thanks save my day... Been more that 2 hours trying to understand why is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the credentials as otions when creating the client:

```
$client = new \SoapClient('http://devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/DirectoryService.svc?singleWsdl', array(
    'login' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'trace' => true
));
```